# Is my Mac infected with the Flashback trojan?

Tags: security, malware

I own a 2011 model of MacBook Pro with a Core i7 processor and Snow Leopard. I have found out there is a [trojan horse which now controls 600,000 Macs](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/over-600000-macs-infected-with-flashback-trojan/11345).

- How can I find out if my MacBook is being controlled?
- How can I remove the trojan?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can follow [these instructions from F-Secure](http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan-downloader_osx_flashback_i.shtml) to uninstall/remove the malware:

1. Run the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   defaults read /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info LSEnvironment
   ```
2. Take note of the value, `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`
3. Proceed to step 8 if you got the following error message:

   ```
   "The domain/default pair of (/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info, LSEnvironment) does not exist"
   ```
4. Otherwise, run the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   grep -a -o '__ldpath__[ -~]*' %path_obtained_in_step2%
   ```
5. Take note of the value after `"__ldpath__"`
6. Run the following commands in Terminal (first make sure there is only one entry, from step 2):

   ```
   sudo defaults delete /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info LSEnvironment`

   sudo chmod 644 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info.plist`
   ```
7. Delete the files obtained in steps 2 and 5
8. Run the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   defaults read ~/.MacOSX/environment DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
   ```
9. Take note of the result. Your system is already clean of this variant if you got an error message similar to the following:

   ```
   "The domain/default pair of (/Users/joe/.MacOSX/environment, DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES) does not exist"
   ```
10. Otherwise, run the following command in Terminal:

    ```
    grep -a -o '__ldpath__[ -~]*' %path_obtained_in_step9%
    ```
11. Take note of the value after `"__ldpath__"`
12. Run the following commands in Terminal:

    ```
    defaults delete ~/.MacOSX/environment DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

    launchctl unsetenv DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
    ```
13. Finally, delete the files obtained in steps 9 and 11.

### Update:

Apple has released an official tool for uninstalling the malware. Read about it and download it on [this Apple KB page.](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1517)

F-Secure has also released a removal tool, which you can download [here.](http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002346.html)

Comment: Ok, I got the error message in both step 3( and step 9). Does that mean I am safe?

Comment: @RichardKnop Yes. You are fine. Thanks for asking the question, BTW.

Answer (score 9):

## [Flashback Checker](https://github.com/jils/FlashbackChecker/wiki)

This is for your relatives and friends that want to **avoid using the Terminal**.

Download this free app from Github. As referenced in this [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1166278/free_flashback_checker_finds_out_if_your_mac_is_infected.html), the single-function app will quickly check your machine for the infection. **The app doesn't remove the malware**, which will be left up to the user by manually following the instructions from [F-secure](http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan-downloader_osx_flashback_i.shtml).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Kaspersky's removal tool

...checks if your Mac is affected and **removes** the trojan if necessary. You can download it on
 **http://support.kaspersky.com/downloads/utils/flashfake_removal_tool.zip**

[image]

## Check online using your UUID

You can check if you Mac is affected using your UUID (Universally unique identifier) on **http://flashbackcheck.com/**

1. Go to:

   ```
    /Applications/Utilites/System Information.app
   ```

   [image]
2. Check the UUID on **http://flashbackcheck.com/**

Answer (score 2):

### Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 8

Apple released an official software update that will *remove* the flashback malware from your computer. Just run software update on your Mac to install it. Here are the details from the [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5243?viewlocale=en_US):

> This Java security update removes the most common variants of the Flashback malware.

### Java for OS X Lion 2012-003

From the [Lion update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5242):

> This Java security update removes the most common variants of the Flashback malware.
>
> This update also configures the Java web plug-in to disable the automatic execution of Java applets. Users may re-enable automatic execution of Java applets using the Java Preferences application. If the Java web plug-in detects that no applets have been run for an extended period of time it will again disable Java applets.

Here is an Apple support article about the [security content](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5247) of the Java updates.

Answer (score 2):

Quick one-liner to paste into **Terminal.app**:

```
defaults read /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Info LSEnvironment &> /dev/null && echo "You seem to have Type 1"; defaults read ~/.MacOSX/environment DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES &> /dev/null && echo "You seem to have Type 2"
```

Unless this outputs anything, you're clean (at least of the known types). If it does say something, [go clean up](http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan-downloader_osx_flashback_i.shtml).